# Arch Linux not added to grub, why?

Tags: grub

I have multiple Linux distributions installed, and currently, Grub is managed by the Manjaro installation. However, after a recent update, the menu entry to boot into Arch is missing.

Running:

```
pacman -S grub
```

reinstall grub but does not add Arch Linux.

Running

```
update-grub
```

outputs:

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found theme: /usr/share/grub/themes/manjaro/theme.txt
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.10-x86_64
Found initrd image: /boot/amd-ucode.img /boot/initramfs-5.10-x86_64.img
Found initrd fallback image: /boot/initramfs-5.10-x86_64-fallback.img
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4-x86_64
Found initrd image: /boot/amd-ucode.img /boot/initramfs-5.4-x86_64.img
Found initrd fallback image: /boot/initramfs-5.4-x86_64-fallback.img
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.
Found Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (22.04) on /dev/nvme0n1p2
Found Arch Linux on /dev/nvme0n1p3
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+/memtest.bin
/usr/bin/grub-probe: warning: unknown device type nvme0n1.
done
```

os-probe seems to see arch linux. But still it's not getting added to the boot menu. Any idea why?

Comment: `pacman -S grub` is only the first step of getting grub to work. It installs the grub package on the system but doesn’t make it operational. Manjaro may be different but on Arch you have to install grub to the drive with `sudo grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=esp --bootloader-id=GRUB` and then create the grub configuration with `sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

Comment: Check the specific instructions on the Manjaro wiki https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php/GRUB/Restore_the_GRUB_Bootloader

Comment: The problem disappeared with an update inside Manjaro.